# Why app:theme is not working tn xml file?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to learn android material design. Working with toolbar i want to change the popup menu as well as text color. So i found that it can be done by adding below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp"

    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But the problem is **app:theme** and **app:popupTheme** is not working and showing error in android studio xml file.

[image]

What can i do know?

I am using **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0**

Comment: add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the Toolbar, in the xml

Comment: Is it too hard to put your cursor on that line? IDE is the powerful tool, it gives you a tip there, all you need is to press Alt+Enter, but instead of this you are posting a question here... downvote

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I am on Visual Studio and no tip pops up so that question was helpful to me. But thanks to you, I now know that if any namespace mess in xml android files, I might put them on Android Studio to get tips!

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the namespace in your xml file.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Somenthing like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```

Also since [appcompat v22.1](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) you can use in the `Toolbar` :

```
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```